# In Java, Remove duplicate files from a list of Files

Tags: java, file, collections, duplicates

I have a list of `java.io.File`.  I would like to force this list to be unique.

It is correct to put them in an HashSet?  like:

```
List<File> list = ...

List<File> newList = new ArrayList<File>(new HashSet<File>(list))
```

Or there is a better way?

Comment: Looks good to me. I d use a set like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to have the collection type to be Set so that anybody reading your code will know outright that you are dealing with a unique set of Files

```
List<File> list = ...

Set<File> files = new HashSet<File>(list);
```

It will also be a bit faster.